# ¿Hay errores en mi código?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax

Estoy intentando pasar datos con AJAX en Laravel, les mostraré un poco mi script y como intento recoger los datos en mi controlador. Cada vez que ejecuto pues me indica que los datos están en null por ende no registra en las tablas, antes hice un código similar que funcionó bien pero ahora no encuentro el error.

Al parecer los únicos datos que recoge son los los del primer array pero los otros datos no los pasa a mi controlador.

Mi código JavaScript:

```
$('#guardar').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).parents('form');
  var array = new Array();
  var array2 = new Array();
  var array3 = new Array();
  var cont1 = 0;
  var cont2 = 0;
  var tot = 0;
  var controlador = 0;
  var x;
  var nro = $("#nro").val();
  var fec = $("#fecha").val();
  var idficha = $("#idficha").val();
  var url = 'registrar';

  @foreach($pre as $preg)

  if (document.getElementById('{{$preg->id}}').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('{{$preg->id}}').value = 1;
    array[cont1] = $('{{$preg->id}}').val();
    array2[cont1] = {
      {
        $preg - > id
      }
    };
    cont2 = $('{{$preg->id}}').val(); + cont2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('{{$preg->id}}').value = 0;
    array[cont1] = $('{{$preg->id}}').val();
    array2[cont1] = {
      {
        $preg - > id
      }
    };
    cont2 = $('{{$preg->id}}').val(); + cont2;
  }

  cont1++;

  @endforeach
  tot = cont2;
  nro = {
    {
      $maxi
    }
  };
  fec = {
    {
      $fec
    }
  };
  idficha = {
    {
      $idce - > id
    }
  };
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  if (controlador == 1) {
    swal('¡Error!', 'No ha calificado a todos los alumnos', 'error');

  } else {

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "post",
      dataType: 'json',

      data: {
        array: array,
        array2: array2,

        nro: nro,
        idficha: idficha,
        fec: fec,
        tot: tot

      },
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.success) {
          //Refresh
          window.location.reload();
        }
      }
    });

    console.log(array);
    console.log(array2);
    console.log(fec);
    console.log(idficha);

    form.submit();
    swal('¡Registrado!', 'Se Guardó Correctamente', 'success');
  }
});

javascript: window.history.forward(1);
```

La función PHP:

```
public function postRegistrar(Request $request) {
  $idficha=$request->idficha;
  $nro=$request->nro;
  $fec=$request->fecha;

  $preguntas= $request->get('array2');

  $resp = $request->get('array');
  $tot = $request->get('cont1');

  $date = date('Y-m-d');
  $regis = new Visita;  
  $max=Visita::max('id')+1;
  $regis->id = $max;
  $regis->nro=$nro;
  $regis->fecha=$fec;
  $regis->save();

  $max5=Visita::max('id');


  for($i = 0; $i <count($preguntas); $i++) {

  $pv= new PreguntaVisita;  
  $m=PreguntaVisita::max('id')+1;
  $pv->id = $m;
  $pv->idpregunta=$request->array2[$i];
  $pv->idrespuesta=$request->array[$i];
  $pv->idficha=$idficha;
  $pv->save();


  };

  $t = new Total;  
  $max6=Total::max('id')+1;
  $t->id = $max6;
  $t->idvisita=$max5;
  $t->total=$tot;
  $regis->save();

  return redirect('rvisita');
}
```

Comment: @VanessaDayámChávezZorrilla Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve]. Debes [edit] la pregunta en lugar de añadir nueva información en los comentarios o respuestas. Completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: Quizás deberías incluir el formulario para que viésemos qué es lo que se está procesando.

Comment: Quizá deberías hacer un `dd($request);` en tu `postRegistrar()` para comprobar qué está siendo enviado al controlador. También deberías echar un vistazo a la consola de depuración de red del navegador para ver qué campos está enviando en la petición HTTP.